# How do I pass a class to another class from within that class?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to pass GameStateManager to MenuState, and this works in java:

```
public class GameStateManager {

    public GameStateManager() {
        MenuState menuState = new MenuState(this);
    }

}
```

But, how can you do this with python? I've tried:

```
from menuState import MenuState

class GameStateManager():

    def __init__(self):
        menuState = MenuState(self)
```

But this doesn't work... And I can't find why/the actual way to do this

Comment: Yes, and how did that not work? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: And please try not to use Camel Casing in python. Its a pain to eyes.

Comment: And tell us what have you tried and whats not working?

Comment: CamelCasing is the appropriate casing for class names according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names).

Comment: @kindall but not for local variables! Or modules! The horror of horrors! ;)

Comment: I can understand about CamelCasing for classnames. But I more emphasizing on the variable used and the filename.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga exactly.